# TFS 2015.3 Release Management Update Release Description After The Fact

Tags: tfs-2015, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to update a Release's Description after it's created? It seems that you get one chance when you create it, but if you miss it, you cannot add/update the description afterward.

On-prem TFS 2015 Update 3.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t update a release’s description in TFS. This feature is available on Visual Studio Team Services.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the release description. Click on the highlighted in the image below to open the dialog.
[image]

Comment: What version of TFS do you have? I don't have that option under "Details."