# How to change TFS 2015 Release description programmatically

Tags: tfs-2015

I'm using TFS 2015 (on premises version) release management. My release is initiated when a new artifact is created - a build of a build definition (name example *MyBuildDefinition*) is finished successfully. When a new release is initiated it receives a description like "*Triggered by MyBuildDefinition 17198.2.*". I'd like to change that default description and add some text to it by a script, for example Power-Shell. Is it possible at all and how to do this?

I've found a [related article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655981/tfs-2015-3-release-management-update-release-description-after-the-fact), but a possibility to change the description manually was discussed in it. I need to do pretty much the same иге with a script.

Answer (score 0):

**Manual :**

We can’t change a release’s description in TFS 2015. This feature is only available on TFS 2017 Update2 and Visual Studio Team Services.

**Programmatic :**

We cannot find the API to modify the description. We can only modify the status of a release. So we can't achieve that with script too. See [Release Management API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases) for details.

[image]

Comment: @Lysenko Alexander Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: No, we did not found a suitable solution, so use it as is for now.